# Regex for alphanumeric

Tags: php, regex, alphanumeric

I've this PHP regular expression:

```
$username = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', '', $username);
```

It allows only `A-Z` and `0-9`. How can I allow `.`, `-` and `_` as well?

Comment: You may find http://www.regular-expressions.info/index.html useful.

Comment: I really advice you to read some introductions to regular expressions. There are a lot tutorials out there, e.g. the one jasonbar linked to. Don't get me wrong, it is fine that you ask questions here, but you should try to solve your problem on your own first.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the following regex:

```
/[^a-z0-9._-]/i
```

- i at the end is to make the pattern
  matching case-insensitive. You can
  drop it and use: `/[^a-zA-Z0-9._-]/`
- -(hyphen) has a special meaning in char class if its surrounded on both
  sided so we put it at the end so that
  its treated literally. You can also
  do: `/[^a-z0-9.\-_]/` where we are
  escaping the hyphen
- A dot in a char class is not a meta
  char hence will be treated literally
  and need not be escaped.

Comment: Why is this regex winking at me? O_O;;

Answer (score 2):

Easy, just add those characters to the regular expression as well

```
$username = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9._-]/','',$username)
```

The . needs to be escaped because its the 'matchall' character, the - goes in the end because otherwise it would be used to define a range (we could ofcourse have just escaped it).

Comment: The `.` doesn't need escaping inside a character group.

Answer (score 1):

```
$username = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9._-]/i', '', $username);
```

Removes anything that *isn't* (`[^]`) one of the characters on the group. Note the hypern is the last one there, so it loses its special meaning.

Comment: I always thought a hyphen only meant something when between letters or numbers - what would `$username = preg_replace('/[^_-.]/i', '', $username);` do?

Comment: it will mind characters **between** `_` and `.`, which is just weird.

Comment: interesting - so presumably all characters with decimal values between 95 (`_`) and 46 (`.`)? Wonder if that would equate to `.-_`.

Comment: Also, someone checked and found that `/[^a-z0-9._-]+/i` is better here, but that's optimizing.

Answer (score 1):

If you know exactly what you need to match, just specify it in a character group. The dash either needs to be at the very start or very end.

```
/[A-Z0-9._-]/
```

Comment: In the answer that was deleted, you said that escaping the DOT will cause the backslash to be matched too, this is not true. Try it: `preg_match_all('/[\.]/', '.\\', $matches); print_r($matches);` Adding a single backslash does nothing, it will just match the literal DOT inside a character class.

Comment: Since preg_replace() is being used they would need to negate this.

Answer (score 1):

```
$username = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9._-]/i', '', $username);
```

Your current code actually does allow both `A-Z` and `a-z` - the `i` flag marks your regular expression as case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

```
$username = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9._-]/i', '', $username);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$username = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9.-_]/i', '', $username);
```

Comment: You need to escape the last hyphen as : .\-_